# How to get confirmation on every Z3 query?

Tags: z3

I am using a remote Z3 console by sending queries through the standard input and reading stdout/err for errors and responses. The problem is I don't see a way to reasonably check if the query has been successfully executed without falling into data races.

#### Example of issue:

Let's say I send a query

```
(assert (= 1 1))
```

Which returns no output. How am I supposed to check if there were any errors there? If I check if there is no response I cannot distinguish a successful query from a still computing operation.

#### Actual question

I would like to make Z3 reply with `ok` or something like that with every query that would normally be silent on success. Is that achievable? If not, what can I do in order to know the status of the most recent query?

Comment: See Figure 3.9 (pg 47) of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf on what legitimate answers you can get after setting `:print-success`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `(set-option :print-success true)` should do exactly that.